# Kernel Panic when using webbrowser / help appreciated

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

I recently had 4 kernel panics on my Macbook Pro (2010), always when using a Webbrowser(newest Firefox / Chrome)

I built in a new SSD two weeks ago, after my old HD was destroyed while having similar panics.

First thing I tried out now was running hardware test, but I dont have OS on a drive and running the internet version returns the error screen "apple.com/support -3403D"

Im running OS X 10.10, here are my logs:
thanks in advance for any suggestion, where they could come from..

22.12.16:

```
Anonymous UUID:       DE1FD5FB-B587-31A4-9B3B-D4970FE93C69

Thu Dec 22 23:53:57 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801e816df2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801ec11bd8, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000011c099004, CR3: 0x000000011f3110ab, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff8030a5b7b2, RCX: 0x0000ffffff801ee7, RDX: 0xffffff802e31dd30
RSP: 0xfffnff80ae813c30, RBP: 0xffffff80ae813c50, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0xffffff8030a5b7b2
R8:  0x0000000000000003, R9:  0x0000000000000fa0, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff802e31dc80, R13: 0xffffff802c8c7c20, R14: 0xffffff801ec27fe3, R15: 0x0000000000000001
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff801ec11bd8, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x000000011c099004, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x3

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80ae795e10 : 0xffffff801e72ad21 
0xffffff80ae795e90 > 0xffffff801e816df2 
0xffffff80ae796050 : xffffff801e833ca3 
0xffffff80ae796070 : 0xffffff801ec11bd8 
0xffffff80ae813c50 : 0xffffff801ec27fe3 
0xffffff80ae813c80 : 0xffffff801ec2!2ed 
0xffffff80ae813cb0 : 0xffffff801ec16cba 
0xffffff80ae813dc0 : 0xffffff<01ec26c0b 
0xffffff80ae813e80 : 0xffffff801ec23ff9 
0xffffff80ae813f50 : 0xffffff801ec4b376 
0xffffff80ae813fb0 : 0xffffff801e8344a6 

BSD process name corresponding to currdnt thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
D!rwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45c7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x000000001e400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801e600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801e500000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1216334346771
last loaded kext at 7014231452: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7fa0c81000$ size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 194653496519: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9fb3b000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
at.obdev.nke.LittleCnitch   4352
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_M`c_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUs%rClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701EtherneT    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.!@@APIC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfivewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.#.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IKEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

and 3 of them today:
first:

```
Anonymous UUID:       DE1FD5FB-B587-31A4-9B3B-D4970FE93C69

Fri Dec 30 19:45:07 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8010816df2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80107ce393, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000030, CR3: 0x0000000007589039, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000030, RBX: 0xffffff8016113e40, RCX: 0x0000000000000030, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff80a7583a60, RBP: 0xffffff80a7583a90, RSI: 0x000000004759d468, RDI: 0xffffff80149bb7f0
R8:  0x0000000000000023, R9:  0xfffffffffffff000, R10: 0x000ffffffffff000, R11: 0xffffff802278e3f0
R12: 0x00000000000eefe4, R13: 0xffffff8014544000, R14: 0xffffff80149bb7f0, R15: 0xffffff7f80000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010207, RIP: 0xffffff80107ce393, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000030, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80a7583710 : 0xffffff801072ad21 
0xffffff80a7583790 : 0xffffff8010816df2 
0xffffff80a7583950 : 0xffffff8010833ca3 
0xffffff80a7583970 : 0xffffff80107ce393 
0xffffff80a7583a90 : 0xffffff80107d0ad8 
0xffffff80a7583ab0 : 0xffffff80107d0c56 
0xffffff80a7583b10 : 0xffffff80107b4b43 
0xffffff80a7583b90 : 0xffffff80107bbdca 
0xffffff80a7583bd0 : 0xffffff80107bbb5e 
0xffffff80a7583c00 : 0xffffff80107b2f95 
0xffffff80a7583c40 : 0xffffff80107ac4ac 
0xffffff80a7583d50 : 0xffffff80107a22ac 
0xffffff80a7583d80 : 0xffffff801074d5b7 
0xffffff80a7583dc0 : 0xffffff8010bc12e9 
0xffffff80a7583e30 : 0xffffff8010bd8b12 
0xffffff80a7583eb0 : 0xffffff8010bd8fe7 
0xffffff80a7583ef0 : 0xffffff8010727256 
0xffffff80a7583f20 : 0xffffff801081756e 
0xffffff80a7583f40 : 0xffffff8010833c6f 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 P
```

second:

```
Anonymous UUID:       DE1FD5FB-B587-31A4-9B3B-D4970FE93C69

Fri Dec 30 19:50:50 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800f816df2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800fcd9070, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff8017752f24, CR3: 0x00000000a92c3066, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff801c626900, RCX: 0xbeef000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff801d448370
RSP: 0xfffnff807f7c3eb0, RBP: 0xffffff807f7c3ec0, RSI: 0x0000000000000008, RDI: 0xffffff801c626900
R8:  0x00000000043a088e, R9:  0xffffff807f7c3d84, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000246
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff80a61b3990, R14: 0xffffff807f7c4000, R15: 0x00000037d7c9dc22
RFL: 0x0000000000010086, RIP: 0xffffff800fcd9070, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000004000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff8017752f24, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff807f7cfc70 : 0xffffff800f72ad21 
0xffffff807f7cfcf0 : 0xffffff800f816df2 
0xffffff807f7cfeb0 : 0xffffff800f833ca3 
0xffffff807f7cfed0 : 0xffffff800fcd9070 
0xffffff807f7c3ec0 : 0xffffff7f903cb550 
0xffffff807f7c3ee0 : 0xffffff800fcd91f5 
0xffffff807f7c3f10 : 0xffffff7f8ff3f749 
0xffffff807f7c3f50 : 0xffffff7f9256db2c 
0xffffff807f7c3f60 : 0xffffff7f92575cbf 
0xffffff807f7c3f80 : 0xffffff800f8161bb 
0xffffff807f7c3fd0 : 0xffffff800f833e69 
0xffffff80a61b3be0 : 0xffffff800f93679b 
0xffffff80a61b3c20 : 0xffffff800f988f65 
0xffffff80a61b3d20 : 0xffffff800fb3e70a 
0xffffff80a61b3db0 : 0xffffff800f964141 
0xffffff80a61b3e50 : 0xffffff800fbeba4a 
0xffffff80a61b3ef0 : 0xffffff800&bebbbe 
0xffffff80a61b3f50 > 0xffffff800fc4b376 
0xffffff80a61b3fb0 : 0xffffff800f8344a6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f8ff24000->0xffffff7f8ff52fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(3.1)[F47C06CE-5C49-3BB4-B642-146F9163EB61]@0xffffff7f92567000->0xffffff7f925c5fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f901f7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f8ff24000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f903c5000->0xffffff7f9062efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f8ff24000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f903b5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f9036e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: firefox

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x000000000f400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800f600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800f500000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 239843694146
last loaded kext at 8274427649: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f91ceb000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 122089511339: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f90ba0000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4352
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

and third:

```
Anonymous UUID:       DE1FD5FB-B587-31A4-9B3B-D4970FE93C69

Fri Dec 30 23:55:54 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8003816df2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80037a6fc2, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000103602000, CR3; 0x000000007c95406c, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000001, RBX: 0x0000ffffff801a34, RCX: 0xffffff8098f7bd80, RDX: 0x0000000002000069
RSP: 0xfffnff8098f7bc30, RBP: 0xffffff8098f7bca0, RSI: 0xffffff80140102e0, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x000000000174f020, R9:  0xffffff8098f7bd80, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000087
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000ffffff8013eb, R14: 0xffffff800f546870, R15: 0xffffff800f546870
RFL: 0x0000000000010203, RIP: 0xffffff80037a6fc2, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000004000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000103602000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8073702c70 : 0xffffff800372ad21 
0xffffff8073702cf0 : 0xffffff8003816df2 
0xffffff8073702eb0 : 0xffffff8003833ca3 
0xffffff8073702ed0 : 0xffffff80037a6fc2 
0xffffff8098f7bca0 : 0xffffff80037a6a31 
0xffffff8098f7bdd0 : 0xffffff800377a785 
0xffffff8098f7be10 : 0xffffff800372ef8c 
0xffffff8098f7be40 : 0xffffff80037139f3 
0xffffff8098f7be90 : 0xffffff800372429d 
0xffffff8098f7bf10 : 0xffffff800380231a 
0xffffff8098f7bfb0 : 0xffffff80038344c6 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: crashpad_handler

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x0000000003400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8003500000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 13530347558004
last loaded kext at 7473311210: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f85ceb000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 123619425824: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f84ba0000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4352
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: Not sure if it's absolutely the reason, but your Little Snitch is a year & several vital bug-fixes out of date. Some reported to cause kernel panics.

Comment: Thank you for having a look. I will try out a newer version, but still I doubt it's the reason, since I'm running exactly the same version of Little Snitch on exactly the same OS on my Mac G5 without having any problems..

Comment: Hello, so changing Little Snitch didnt work, I installed the newest Version and my Mac is still crashing while using a webbrowser. If I could, I would upload a Diagnostics Report of Chrome, but I'm exceeding the 30k symbols allowed..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's my **temporary solution:**

I took out one of the two RAM bars and left the one in the lower slot: the macbook crashed immediately.

THEN: I put the same RAM bar into the upper slot and since then I didn't have any crashes ..

still don't know what this means... Is it about the RAM or is it about the Motherboard? Does it make sense to buy new RAM for the other buggy slot?

edit:

First: AHT didnt show any errors.

Second: I tested all possible configuration with my RAM and used the macbook for a while:

Any RAM-Module would work in the upper RAM-slot.
But putting the RAM into the lower slot, it crashes, no matter which RAM I use.

SO the slot is broken and I'm tied to using only one RAM module?

Comment: Rather than creating an "answer" to update your question ***edit your original question*** with the new details.    As for what you discovered, you need to test with the other module.   You also want to do this with [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ran apple hardwaretest with no results, downgraded to mountain lion (the last OS running without problems) and reset smc and pram, the macbook is still having random crashes. The only thing changed is that I get strange graphic glitches now and no crash reports anymore, before it was only randomly shut down..
So nothing changed I guess